# Pygame: Removing an entity from a list

Tags: python, pygame

I am attempting to create a small, simple game. But I am having a lot of trouble so far. (I'm fairly new to pygame)

The problem is raised from this code:

```
    #The blocks' code
    for block in blocklist:
        #Blocks Collide
        if any(block.rect.colliderect(x.rect) for x in blocklist if x is not block):
            x=(int(mse[0]) / 32)*32
            y=(int(mse[1]) / 32)*32
            blockpairs = itertools.combinations(blocklist,2) #2 for pairs
            remlist = frozenset(b2 for b1,b2 in blockpairs if b1.rect.colliderect(b2.rect))
            blocklist = [block for block in blocklist if block not in remlist]
            for block in remlist:
                print 'killed it'
                blocklist.remove(block)
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\samis_000\Desktop\blockgame.pyw", line 43, in <module>
    blocklist.remove(block)
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

I don't understand what is going wrong!

Here is the code as a whole:

```
#Import required modules
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import itertools
pygame.init()
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((640,480),0)

#Define class for the blocks
class Block(object):

    sprite = pygame.image.load("dirt.png").convert_alpha()

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.rect = self.sprite.get_rect(top=y, left=x)

#Create the list for the blocks
blocklist = []

#Main Loop
while True:
    #Test for events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        #Left mouse released event
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            mse=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            x=(int(mse[0]) / 32)*32
            y=(int(mse[1]) / 32)*32
            blocklist.append(Block(x,y))
        #Close button event
        if event.type == QUIT:
            exit()
    #The blocks' code
    for block in blocklist:
        #Blocks Collide
        if any(block.rect.colliderect(x.rect) for x in blocklist if x is not block):
            x=(int(mse[0]) / 32)*32
            y=(int(mse[1]) / 32)*32
            blockpairs = itertools.combinations(blocklist,2) #2 for pairs
            remlist = frozenset(b2 for b1,b2 in blockpairs if b1.rect.colliderect(b2.rect))
            blocklist = [block for block in blocklist if block not in remlist]
            for block in remlist:
                print 'killed it'
                blocklist.remove(block)
        #Display blocks
        screen.blit(block.sprite, block.rect)
    #Update the screen
    pygame.display.update()
```

I also need to be able to implement this in a way to where I can remove blocks by clicking them.

Sorry if this is too much to ask :/

Comment: I don't get it. `blocklist` are the items which are NOT IN `remlist`. Then you take a block from `remlist` and try to remove it from `blocklist` ?

Comment: I got that code from a previous thread in which I asked the same question, I don't get it either.

Comment: Well, try understanding this... Since there's a very obvious bug right there. Are you trying to study python? This is the best way to do so...

Comment: I am not studying python, I merely have been practicing/using it in my free time for 2 or 3 years now.

Comment: What do you think you should do then to fix this code?

Comment: I have no idea. That is why I posted it here, in hopes that someone else could guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea what you are trying here:

```
if any(block.rect.colliderect(x.rect) for x in blocklist if x is not block):
            x=(int(mse[0]) / 32)*32
            y=(int(mse[1]) / 32)*32
            blockpairs = itertools.combinations(blocklist,2) #2 for pairs
            remlist = frozenset(b2 for b1,b2 in blockpairs if b1.rect.colliderect(b2.rect))
            blocklist = [block for block in blocklist if block not in remlist]
            for block in remlist:
                print 'killed it'
                blocklist.remove(block)
```

If you want to create and remove blocks by clicking with the mouse, have a look at this example (should be pretty easy to follow):

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((640,480))

class Block(object):
    sprite = pygame.image.load("dirt.png").convert_alpha()
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        # since x and y will be the mouse position,
        # let x and y be the center of the block
        self.rect = self.sprite.get_rect(centery=y, centerx=x)

blocklist = []

while True:
    # don't forget to clear the screen
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT: exit()
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP: 
            # get all blocks that "collide" with the current mouse position
            to_remove = [b for b in blocklist if b.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos)]
            for b in to_remove:
                blocklist.remove(b)

            # if we didn't remove a block, we create a new one
            if not to_remove:
                blocklist.append(Block(*mouse_pos))

    for b in blocklist:
        screen.blit(b.sprite, b.rect)

    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Finally someone got it!! But actually this:
x=(int(mse[0]) / 32)*32
y=(int(mse[1]) / 32)*32
Was required... because it snaps the blocks to a 32x32 grid.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You do

```
blocklist = [block for block in blocklist if block not in remlist]
```

so all the blocks from `remlist` are no longer in `blocklist`...

```
for block in remlist:
    print 'killed it'
```

...so you can't remove them...

```
    blocklist.remove(block)
```

so an error is thrown. Just remove that last line and it should stop the error.